# Django refer to models defined in another application -> empty QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an app called projects with a model Project, that I want to refer in another app called map that has the model MapData. So I can use/access the data from Project in map.html template.

According to the Django Docs.

> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly specify a model with the full application label. For example, if the Manufacturer model above is defined in another application called production, you’d need to use:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
        'production.Manufacturer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

---

from projects.models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
    featured_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='projects/featured', blank=True)
    lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8, default=1)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8, default=1)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

from map.models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from projects.models import Project

class MapData(models.Model):
    map_data = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

But when I access to shell, I just get an empty QuerySet:

```
>>> from map.models import MapData
>>> MapData.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

In regards to my map.models.py file, I have tried `OneToOneField(Project)` giving me same result. And I've tried `map_data = models.ForeignKey(projects.Project)` giving me a NameError, and putting `map_data = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project')` in quotes, also giving me an empty QuerySet.

Can someone please explain what I'm not understanding here. All I want is to be able to access `project.lat`, `project.lon`, `project.title` and `project.featured_image` in my map.html template.

Comment: Did you save some MapData instances before?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Or I have made a few migrations.

Comment: So how do you expect to get results when you run `MapData.objects.all()`?

Comment: You need to create `Project` and `MapData` instances first

Comment: Take a look at my below answer and try the do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected result if you did not save any `MapData` instance before. Try this to understand better how your models work:

```
>>> from map.models import MapData
>>> from projects.models import Project
>>>
>>> p1 = Project()
>>> p1.title = 'First Project'
>>> p1.save()  # We save this project in the database!
>>>
>>> md1 = MapData()
>>> md1.map_data = p1  # We use the above project for this md1
>>> md1.save()  # We save md1
>>>
>>> MapData.objects.all()  # You should get the one that we just created
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood when I first answered. I do have 2 instances of projects saved. >>> Project.objects.all() returns 2 instances. And >>> md1.map_data = Project.objects.get(pk=1) returns <QuerySet [<MapData: MapData object>]>


But you are right, running through your steps above does work.

Comment: So you need to use them to create MapData instaces, after that you can run `MapData.objects.all()`

Comment: I think that I could just grap those data from Project without having to create MapData instances...

Comment: Please be clear. I can not understand what you want exactly. If you want just to read `Project` objects yes you can read them through `Project.objects.all()`, if you want to read `MapData` objects use `MapData.objects.all()`

Comment: Sorry. I just want to read Project. I don't want to modify or do anything with the data in the map app. I just want to output a few fields from Project to the map.html html template. Basically just in the same way as I would in the projects_list.html template.

Comment: Well, sort of, you did answer my question. :) But I've not managed to achieve what I need yet. It's not entirely clear in my mind what and how. So I can't properly ask the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! just go through the django tutorials in django website and try to learn things step by step.